# Redirecting through IIS to another local server?

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, iis, subdomain

I have a problem i cant seem to understand in IIS 7.5, OK here goes...

I have a website www.mysite.com that's hosted on my ISP, i have a sub domain drones.mysite.com that gets directed to my home server at IP address 1.1.1.1 which is managed by IIS on a windows 7 PC, i also have another sub domain of cloud.mysite.com that also get directed to 1.1.1.1, again looked after by IIS BUT i have a linux/apache server (on a seperate PC) and i want shop.mysite.com to be directed to the IIS server then redirected internally to my linux server.

From what i've read it needs to be done through HTTP redirect  but i don't want to lose my original directed sites.

Any ideas, cheers in advance

Mark

Comment: Can you give more details like how the sites are hosted on IIS ? Each site on different port or on same port but with specific host name ?

Comment: HI Ravi A, they are all using port 80 but bound to different host names ,i.e cloud website is bound to incoming cloud.mysite.com etc, cheers

Comment: You need to use ARR to achieve this as explained here http://serverfault.com/questions/267136/iis-7-reverse-proxy-based-on-domain-name-host